# Cannot file build style on visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I want to open `The Modify Style dialog box`
Someone may know if this moved ?
I have try  `View->Toolbars->` and from here i cannot fine any style option

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about the Toolbars -> `Style Sheet` toolbar, it seems to have been removed intentionally:

> Thanks for the feedback. The Stylesheet toolbar was removed because it
>   added little to no value with outdated wizards and dialogs. We're
>   looking at bringing more visual tooling back to CSS in the future, but
>   in a better way.
>
> Regards, Mads Kristensen

Source: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807167/vs-rc-ultimate-2013-missing-toolbar-style-sheet

Might be worth keeping an eye on this one as well (for further verification, it may get updated):
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808299/style-sheet-tool-bar-in-visual-studio-2013